# Updating variables in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, random, integer, lifetime

I want to increase the ordinal number of the guess for the current game cycle by 1. i have set the value initially at 0 but it doesnt update after 1
Same goes for number of trys. i have set the value at 21. but as soon it updates until 20 but not after that

```
   Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
    Private value As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.value = rand.Next(minValue:=1, maxValue:=30)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim guess As Integer        'guess number
        Dim numTry As Integer       'No. of trys
        Dim RandNo As Integer       'Random Number
        Dim OrdNo As Integer        'Ordinal Number
        Dim Score As Integer        'Score

        Score = 0 'Initial value of score set as 0
        OrdNo = CInt(1)  'Initial value of ordinal set as 1 
        numTry = CInt(21)
        guess = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        OrdNo = +1
        Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)

        'Show Message Box if the guess is not within the range
        If 1 > guess Then
            MessageBox.Show("Input within the range (1-30)", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Show Message Box if the guess is not within the range
        If guess > 30 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Input within the range (1-30)", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is larger than the lucky number
        If guess > Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "The Lucky Number is smaller than your guess"
            OrdNo = OrdNo + 1
            Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            Label4.Text = CStr(numTry)
        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is smaller than lucky number
        If guess < Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "The Lucky Number is larger than your guess"
            OrdNo = OrdNo + 1
            Label5.Text = CStr(OrdNo)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            Label4.Text = CStr(numTry)

        End If

        'Display result and message when guess is equal to the lucky number
        If guess = Me.value Then
            Label11.Text = CStr(guess)
            Label10.Text = "Congratulations ! This is the lucky number"
            Score = +10 'Increase the score by 10
            Label6.Text = CStr(Score)
            numTry = numTry - 1
            OrdNo = 1
            Me.value = rand.Next(minValue:=1, maxValue:=30)

            If numTry = 0 Then Application.Exit()

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What error you are getting. What doesn't work?

Comment: I think he wants the number to always be the same until they guess it correct, however from looking at this code, im guessing it will change the random number each time it is guessed wrong.

Comment: Please learn to debug..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Button event-handler, `RandNo` is always **Zero**. Take into account that the lifetime of the variable with the same name `RandNo` that is declared in the Form Load event-handler, only remains to that method.

To avoid that, follow these steps:

First (but optionally), use the **[Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** Class, ensure to initialize it just once (otherwise you can get repeated numbers as explained in the MSDN documentation).

Secondly, declare the **Integer** variable that will store the random value just once, in the same way outside of the scope of a method block, assign its value and work done:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly rand As New Random
    Private value As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.value = rand.Next(minValue:=0, maxValue:=100)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
        ' Do what you want with Me.value
        '...
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I dont quite get it. it still generates nothing. could u do it again ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9w9ckp3ffwds9i/asg1_test.exe?dl=0                   I want to make a game like this. Suggest edits to the code please

Comment: Sorry but No, I'm not gonna download the project to do your job!, we are here to help you understand how you can do it, I've explained how you can solve the main problem, if you still have doubts, ask concretely for what doubts you are having, note that you can update your question to add your advances in the code that you are building and explaining any problem related with the code that I shown.

Comment: Sorry but I am not asking you to do my job. Thanks anyways !

Comment: @Varun Fatehpuria Seeying your last edit, "Me.Value" cannot be zero in the Button event-handler, please, do a single check at the top of that method block with a simple **msgbox(me.value)** to let you know the actual number!

Comment: Yes its not zero. I deleted that comment

Comment: I have edited the question. Would be great if you could help further

Comment: I do not want to seem rude, but if this question is solved you should accept one of the published answers that solved your problem, then create a new question in StackOverflow to explain your new problem instead of completely changing this question!

Comment: Get it. My first time here. !